# How to remove 00:00:00 from a Date in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime, formatdatetime

I have a datatable (returned by database using dataadaptor) with a `DateOfBirth` field with `00:00:00` at the end of date of birth. I want to remove those 00:00:00 so I wrote a function but it doesn't do the job and I don't know why. Can anyone suggest to me how to remove the `00:00:00` from `DateOfBirth`. I don't have permission to the database or the stored procedure.

```
    Dim DOB As New DateTime
    Dim newDob As String = ""

        For Each x In dt.Rows

            If x("DateOfBirth") <> String.Empty AndAlso IsDate(x("DateOfBirth")) Then

                DOB = CDate(x("DateOfBirth"))
                newDob = DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                x("DateOfBirth") = newDob

            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove the `00:00:00` from a date **value**, just from a date **string**. You can remove it when showing a date string by `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` as you did, but `x("DateOfBirth")` is a date value (as written in your if statement), and it measures the ticks (10 pow -7 of a second) from 1/1/1970 (sql `datetime`) or 1/1/0001 (sql `datetime2` or c# `DateTime`). A date value doesn't have any string representation, only when you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` entry in your `datarow` is a blob of binary data in practice. The `00:00:00` is just the string representation of it. What you are doing is putting `21/1/1978` into the date field, but as far as the computer is concerned this is the same date as `21/1/1978 00:00:00` so what you are doing has no effect.

What you should be doing is adjusting the display of the date when you are outputting it to a string wherever you are viewing it. There you can use the `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` to format it as you want.